# Any "Always On Top" app working on Mojave?

Tags: macos, mojave, window-manager

My workflow requires a lot of coding, and sometimes pasting code from a text editor to a terminal window. In those occasions, keeping the terminal window "always on top" is very convenient.

Up until High Sierra, I used to use mySIMBL with its "Afloat" plugin. It was quite tricky to get it working - one had to disable SIP, install mySIMBL and re-enable SIP again - but it worked fine. It looked like this:

[image]

With Mojave, however, it no longer works. Actually, it does - but SIP must be permanently disabled. I mean not only for installing it, but for using it as well. And I don't want to take the risk of using Mojave with SIP permanently disabled.

So, I'm looking for a replacement. Does anyone know an alternative way of making a window stay on top in macOS Mojave? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need it for a terminal app, I'm pretty sure iTerm2 still knows this: https://www.iterm2.com/features.html